# Failure to get a list of avaliable SQL Server instances using SqlDataSourceEnumerator

Tags: sql-server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

static void Main()
{
    string conn = @"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=true;";

    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", sqlConn.State);
    }

    SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
    System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();
    System.Data.DataRow[] rows = table.Select();

    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row["ServerName"]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I have a single SQL Server Express instance running.

When I launch this program, it says "Status: Open" but fails to show the name of the server. Why might that be? I know for sure that there is one server up and running.

I picked (and adapted a little) the second half of the code from the MSDN page "[SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.instance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Sql_SqlDataSourceEnumerator_Instance)"

When I use a breakpoint to peek into the contents of `rows[]`, I see that they are empty.

The program does not throw any errors, it just does not show the name of the server.

Comment: When in doubt, read the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Sql_SqlDataSourceEnumerator_GetDataSources 
Especially the highlighted note about how `the method will not always return a complete list of the available servers, and the list might not be the same on every call.`

Comment: @TechGnome - thank you! I was sure of the method because it is also used in a piece of code provided by a textbook on C#. Now I know better. I wonder if there is a more reliable method for getting a list of servers.

Comment: Sadly there is not. What I've done in the past to "get around it" is to call it twice, merge what's returned into a distinct list... go with it, and hope for the best. It is the way it is due to latency and responsiveness. Not all SQL Servers are set to broadcast,  and depending on the size and load of networks, getting the list can take a while. So, to make the call "quick" it doesn't wait long and the result is... often incomplete.